# How to evaluate one improper integral

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Please show me the detailed solution to the question:

Compute the value of
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \ln x\right) ^{40021}}{x}dx$$

Thank you a million!

Comment: Hint: Let $u = \log x$, then $du = \frac 1x\, dx$.

Comment: this integral is undefined .

Comment: OK but this leads to the expression minus infinity plus infinity and then what?

Comment: I want to clearly see why this integral diverges

Comment: Because (for example) $\int_e^\infty \frac 1x \, dx$ diverges and you integrand is larger.

Comment: @martini, but in the interval $(0,e)$, the integrand takes large negative values though. How do you account for that?

Comment: @FortuonPaendrag If we are not considering the PV, AFAIK such an integral diverges if it does "on one side".

Comment: @martini Ah, thank you. Like an alternating sum whose terms are only getting bigger in absolute value?.It makes sense now. I should have given it a little more thought.

Answer (score 2):

**Edited**. 
Let $u=\log x$ (as per martini's hint) and $f(u)=u^{40021}$. Then

1. $$\begin{equation*}
   I:=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \log x\right) ^{40021}}{x}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(u)du,
   \end{equation*}$$
2. Function $f$ is odd, $f(-u)=-f(u)$. These integrals don't converge $$
   \begin{equation*}
   \int_{-\infty }^{0}f(u)du=-\int_{0}^{\infty }f(u)du.
   \end{equation*}$$

The integral $I$ is undefined (as commented by pedja).

Comment: Brilliant! I am convinced. Thank you, thank you, thank you :-)

Comment: @Halina, Glad to Help!

Comment: Just a moment: from your step 2, it follows that I=-infinity plus infinity so we are back to square number one again?

Comment: that is, $I=-\infty +\infty $ because $\int_{0}^{\infty }f\left( u\right) du=\infty $

Comment: @Halina Right. Both $\int_{-\infty }^{0}f(u)du$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty }f(u)du$ diverge. $\int_{-\infty }^{0}f(u)du=-\infty$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty }f(u)du=\infty$.

Comment: @Halina  $\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty}f(u)du$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Make the change of variables suggested. You'll end up with $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty u^{40021}du$$ Then the integral is either undefined or taking the principal value, it is $0$.

Comment: How can it be both?

Comment: @Halina I said EITHER underfined, OR taking the PV $0$. Do some research on the Principal Value.

Comment: Ok but can you really apply the substitution rule to improper integrals?

Comment: @Halina, Yes, you can.

Comment: Thank you so very, very much :-)

Comment: Now, please look at this:

Comment: If $u=logx$, then $du=\frac{1}{x}dx$ so $I=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \log x\right) ^{40021}}{dx}=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty }u^{40021}du=\int_{-\infty }^{0}u^{40021}du+\int_{0}^{\infty }u^{40021}du=\lim_{t\rightarrow -\infty }\int_{t}^{0}u^{40021}du+\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }\int_{0}^{t}u^{40021}du=\lim_{t\rightarrow -\infty }\left( -\left( \frac{t^{400022}}{400022}\right) \right) +\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }\left( \frac{t^{400022}}{400022}\right) =-\infty +\infty $

Comment: so how can we conclude from the above that the integral I is divergent ?

Comment: I got it now> Thank you for your patience :-)

Comment: Always double check with what you see with other tools such as Wolfram Alpha, according to which the integral does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

Let me introduce you to elegant mathematics!

$$I_1=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \ln x\right) ^{40021}}{x}dx$$

put $x=\frac{1}{t}$, to get

$$\int\limits_{\infty}^{0 }\frac{\left( \ln \frac{1}{t}\right) ^{40021}}{\frac{1}{t}}.\frac{-dt}{t^2}$$

$$\int\limits_{\infty}^{0 }\frac{\left( \ln t\right) ^{40021}}{t}dt=-\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \ln t\right) ^{40021}}{t}dt=I_1$$

so,

$I_1=-\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \ln t\right) ^{40021}}{t}dt=-\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \ln x\right) ^{40021}}{x}dx$

and

$I_1=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty }\frac{\left( \ln x\right) ^{40021}}{x}dx$

addint the 2 gives $2I_1=0$, hence $I_1 =0$

Comment: that looks like right solution...

Comment: This is deceptive. When we write $\int_{0}^{\infty}$ we are really doing $\lim_{b\to\infty} \int_{0}^b$ and so what we are really doing in this "proof" is adding two functions ($\int_{0}^b$ and $\int_{-b}^0$) whose limits don't exist and claiming that their sum exists.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{{\log x}^{40021}}{x}dx
         &=\lim_{s\to\infty}\int_{0}^{s}\frac{{\log x}^{40021}}{x}dx\\
                                             &=\lim_{s\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{s}u^{40021}du\\
                                             &=\lim_{s\to\infty}\left[\frac{u^{40022}}{40022}\right]_{-\infty}^{s}\\
                                             &=\infty.
\end{align*}
In this i take $\log x= u$. And this example is a improper integral of the third kind.

Comment: What about the other infinity? You have something wrong there. You get $\infty - \infty$, which is indeterminate, so you need to consider the PV.

Comment: exactly, this is what I meant, too

Comment: @Peter: there is no *need* to consider the Principal Value. It is *possible* to consider the the Principal Value. [Technically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral#Convergence_of_the_integral), the integral diverges: $\int_0^\infty\frac{\log(x)^{40021}}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\frac{\log(x)^{40021}}{x}\mathrm{d}x+\int_1^\infty\frac{\log(x)^{40021}}{x}\mathrm{d}x$ and both of these integrals diverge.

Comment: Actually, $\left[\frac{u^{40022}}{40022}\right]_{-\infty}^{s}=-\infty$, so $\lim\limits_{s\to\infty}\left[\frac{u^{40022}}{40022}\right]_{-\infty}^{s}=-\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an exercise on improper integrals, it is natural to replace the
upper and lower limits by $R$, $\frac{1}{R}$ respectively and define the integral to be the limit as $R \rightarrow \infty$ . Then write the integral as the sum of the integral from $\frac{1}{R}$ to $1$ and from $1$ to $R$. In the second integral make the usual transformation replacing $x$ by $\frac{1}{x}$. The two integrals cancel.

Comment: you might wanna look at my answer.